# C# Testing Kaltura player using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, kaltura

I'm going to do some automated testing of our website which has videos played by the Kaltura player. In one of my test I'm going to change the quality settings of the video. Problem is I got no clue on how to fetch that element that is controlling the quality settings from Selenium.

Can anyone confirm if that's possible using Selenium ? If yes, please enlighten me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python bindings but principle is the same though.

**change_quality.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get('http://player.kaltura.com/docs/')

browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#kaltura_player_ifp'))

quality_btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='Quality Settings']")
quality_btn.click()

# old quality
print browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li[aria-checked=true] > a').text

new_quality  = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='360P HQ']")
new_quality.click()

quality_btn.click()

# new quality
print browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li[aria-checked=true] > a').text
```

In action:

```
In [5]: run change_quality.py
720P
360P HQ
```

<sub>Everything is possible!</sub>
<sub>*Next time - firstly show what you tried.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks drets for your help. Perhaps its a stupid question but how did you find out to use the FindBy Css Selector and the names ?

Comment: @user1005448 Thanks, I am using `Elements` panel (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics) and just know how to write css selectors (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching), that's it.